# Will IIS web gardens providing high availability?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application (.NET FW 4.5) that occasionally crashes and has a long startup time due to an in-process cache. I am considering using an IIS walled garden (multiple worker processes) so that if 1 process failed, the other would pick up the load.

Can the walled garden provide this high availability? If so, what should the failed application return to IIS whilst it is building the cache?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541860/what-is-the-difference-between-web-farm-and-web-garden BTW, crashes and long startup time can be resolved (at least partially) if your developers do the right things.

Comment: @LexLi thanks I've looked at that link, but it doesnt specifically address web garden behaviour in terms of fail-over.

Comment: No documentation will be specific to that granularity IMHO. Ask your developers to write a hello world app that crashes randomly and intentionally, so that you can host it in a web garden to observe the behavior.